# How to Enable UI botton in ViewController A upon on row selection in TableViewController B

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uitableview, uitabbar

I have two view controllers (Both Embedded in Navigation Controllers) in tab bar controller. ViewControllerA is has two buttons (MybuttonA and MybuttonB with enabled box unchecked in storyboard). ViewControllerB is a TableViewController. I would like to enable a buttons in ViewControllerA upon selecting specific rows in ViewControllerB table. Each button is expected to push different view controllers when enabled.

My present code works only when ViewControllersA and ViewControllersB are not embedded in Navigation Controllers. But without Navigation controller embedding, the enabled buttons does not push ViewControllers.

ViewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface  ViewControllerA : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIButton * MybuttonA;
IBOutlet UIButton * MybuttonB;

}
-(IBAction)mybuttonaction:(id)sender;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *MybuttonA;
 @property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *MybuttonB;

 @end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerA ()
@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
@synthesize MybuttonA;
@synthesize MybuttonB;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

 }


-(IBAction)mybuttonaction:(id)sender{
     //write code to push view controller
}
```

ViewControllerB.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerB : UITableViewController{

ViewControllerA *viewcontrollerA;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewControllerA *viewcontrollerA;
@end
```

ViewControllerB.m

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
 #import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerB () {

}

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB
@synthesize  viewcontrollerA;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

   self.title = @"CONTENTS";

     self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

  [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload)        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self reload];
 [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

  viewcontrollerA = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];


 }

#pragma mark - Table View

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {return 1;}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  {return 5;}
 }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"    forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Cell #%d", indexPath.row];

 }

 return cell;
 }

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString* value = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;

   if ([value isEqual:@"1"]){
   viewcontrollerA.MybuttonA.enabled=YES;
   }
   else if ([value isEqual:@"2"])
   {
            viewcontrollerA.MybuttonB.enabled=YES;
   }

    }

  else {
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
   }
   }
  @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
viewcontrollerA = ((UINavigationController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] ).topViewController
```

Instead of this:

```
  viewcontrollerA = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: It worked fine. But I have a semantic error: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'ViewControllerA*_strong' from 'UIViewController*'

Comment: viewcontrollerA = ((ViewControllerB*)((UINavigationController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] ).topViewController)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The following worked - viewcontrollerA = ((ViewControllerA*)((UINavigationController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControll‌​ers objectAtIndex:0] ).topViewController)

Answer (score 1):

Use Delegation or 'NSNotification' to pass messages in between objects. Create a protocol for class B and send a message to its delegate when selecting particular row in it and make view controller A conform to this protocol. Make changes in view controller A when it receives the delegate message from view controller B.

Or for a loose broadcasting, you can fire/post a notification on row selection in view controller B and make view controller A a listener to it and change views on the posting of notification.

Although Delegation is the way to go in your case.